# Specify character colours globally in Markdown/CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, markdown

I am working on studying-sheets for R and Python, and I've decided to summarise commands and topics in R-Markdown. I am using an HTML output and via CSS, I've customised the appearance of quoteblocks and code. However, I would also like to highlight certain elements within the code, like ">", "<", and brackets.
Is there a way to output certain characters in different colour using global options in CSS or Markdown?

Comment: Nope. CSS is content "unaware". You can't select a character. The best you can do is warp the brackets in a `<span>` or some other tag and then use CSS to color them. My guess is that would break your code blocks though.

Comment: @disinfor that is unfortunate... Breaking code is not a problem though, the cells I need to run don't need syntax highlighting. Is it possible to define a kind of variable, so that I could define a mod like `<span style="color:blue">blue</span>(</p>` and call that variable in text, so that I do not need to type the whole line every time?